# How to disable automatic window resizing when moving between monitors?

Tags: display, window-manager

When moving a window between monitors of different sizes, the system automatically resizes the window based on the relative dimensions of the source and destination monitors. [Apparently this feature was added in Montery](https://www.macrumors.com/2021/06/09/macos-monterey-automatic-window-resizing/).

I'm not using "Displays have separate spaces".  I have two external monitors on my M1 Max MBP, with one rotated, so I effectively have 3 screen sizes.

[image: Monitor Layout]

This means every time I move a window from one monitor to another, the size changes, and it's never what I want.  Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: This is extremely annoying when iTerm resizes.  I want it to stay at 128x28 no matter what.  Instead, it resizes itself whenever I dock or undock my MacBook Air.